# Bluez 5.40 not reconized when try to install modules

Tags: apt

I have compiled(make ,make install ,etc)  bluez 5.40 on Raspbian Jessie 8 successfuly but if i try :

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

give mean output :

extra packages need to be installed : bluez

If it is already compiled why this ? If i accept install it goes ahead and install APT version alongside compiled version

Answer (score 1):

After some research :

-Getting source code

```
./configure
make
```

then :

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

and still inside the source code folder

```
sudo checkinstall
```

The last command is a tool to install a version of OS package manager .

source : https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall